# Expresión regular para contraseña con símbolos especiales no reconoce símbolo +

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo esta expresión regular para la contraseña en js:

```
if (password.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,(,),+,=,.,{,},:]/) {
```

No reconoce el símbolo del `+`

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a quitar el `.` del principio, ya que si no la expresión no va a tener en cuenta el primer carácter de la contraseña:

```js
password = "+test"

if (password.match(/[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,(,),+,=,.,{,},:]/)) {
  console.log("Contraseña inválida - carácter no permitido");
} else {
  console.log("Contraseña válida");
}
```